# nltk do not recognize list

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a class named `VoteClassifier` as below. I create a list named `unpickled_model` to put all the trained model inside but nltk  do not recognize lists. Do you have an idea please?
Any contribution would be appreciated.

VoteClassifier class:

```
class VoteClassifier(ClassifierI):
    def __init__(self, *classifiers):
        self._classifiers = classifiers

    def classify(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)
        return mode(votes)

    def confidence(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)

        choice_votes = votes.count(mode(votes))
        conf = choice_votes / len(votes)
        return conf

models = MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB, LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier, SVC, LinearSVC

unpickeled_models = []
for model in models:
    classifier_f = open("{0}.pickle".format(model),"rb")
    unpickeled_models.append(pickle.load(classifier_f))
    classifier_f.close()

    
voted_classifier = VoteClassifier(unpickeled_models)
print("voted classifier accuracy pct:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier, testing_set))*100)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 152, in <module>
    print("voted classifier accuracy pct:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier, testing_set))*100)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/classify/util.py", line 91, in accuracy
    results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs, l) in gold])
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 79, in classify_many
    return [self.classify(fs) for fs in featuresets]
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 79, in <listcomp>
    return [self.classify(fs) for fs in featuresets]
  File "model.py", line 45, in classify
    v = c.classify(features)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'classify'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about how you define the `__init__` function with the `*`;

```
def test_function(*classifiers):
    classifiers = classifiers
    print(classifiers)

list_ = ['hello', 'world']

test_function(list_)
```

Outputs a tuple with a list;

```
(['hello', 'world'],)
```

If you remove the `*`;

```
def test_function(classifiers):
    classifiers = classifiers
    print(classifiers)

list_ = ['hello', 'world']

test_function(list_)
```

Outputs a list;

```
['hello', 'world']
```